Blue Prism: Internal : Failed to evaluate expression '[CurrentRow]+1' - Cannot perform + operation when the left-hand value is empty
Error shown in BluePrism
I was trying to calculate the each time the loop passes, it'll store in current row. To resolve this issue make sure that you initialize the your data item '[CurrentRow]+1' by giving it an intitial value.

To resolve this issue make sure that you initialize the your data item '[CurrentRow]+1' by giving it an intitial value.
rpablueprism
